# NCSimulatorPlugin - Does not seems to work

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-plugin

Has anyone tries using [NCSimulatorPlugin](https://github.com/Abhinav77/NCSimulatorPlugin)? I installed the plugin and I can see it inside `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`.

But when I quit and relaunched Xcode and run my app on simulator I do not see shortcut to see Documents apps for Simulator selected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs in the plugins info.plist to make it work for the current version of xcode

to get current xcode UUID:

```
defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID
```

write this in terminal

Add that in the NCSimulatorPlugin's bundle info.plist file under 'DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs' key
you have to add UUID of all the xcode in which you want to use the plugin

Restart the xcode and it will show popup to load the bundle and after that you should able to see the NCSimulatorPlugin in the menu